# Can't set value for Non-relational column in pivot table with Laravel factory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

hey everybody is it technically possible to set data in an extra column in the pivot table?

my database is like

| products | sellers |
| --- | --- |
| id | id |
| title | name |
| brand_id |  |
| and... |  |

| prodduct_sellrs |
| --- |
| id |
| product_id |
| seller_id |
| price |

and I want to Seed my database with factory Faker data and here is my code in my seeder (I've already made the ProductFactory and.... )

```
        Product::factory()
        ->foruser()
       ->hasCategories()
       ->hasTags()
       ->hassellers()
       ->forBrand()
       ->forAttributeSet()
       ->create();
```

but when I run it I get this error

> General error: 1364 Field 'price' doesn't have a default value

which is truly right but anybody can help how I can define value for price in the pivot table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use factory callbacks
[Factory callbacks - Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks)

After create your Product, you can create data for your relational tabble

```php
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Product::class;

    /**
     * Configure the model factory.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (Product $product) {
            $product->sellers()->save(factory(App\ProductSeller::class)->make());
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped but one thing for people who are working laravel 8 ,factory(App\ProductSeller::class is no longer working and you should use it this way

ProductSeller::factory()->create()

Answer (score 0):

I realized my answer If anyone wanted to use

```
       Product::factory()
       ->foruser()
       ->hasCategories()
       ->hasAttached(
            Seller::factory()->count(10),
            ['price'=>423432432]
        )
```

and it solved, here it is